# Configuring filters with vue-test-utils

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-test-utils

How can we configure a component mount with a globally applied filter? I assume it would be some options passed to [createLocalVue](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#createlocalvue), but I don't see it in the docs.

With a global filter in use, I get the following warning in the console when running a suite:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve filter: filterName
```

The string at wrapper.html() includes the precomputed value, with the filter not applied, e.g.

```
{{ 'a string' | throughFilter }}
```

is still

```
'a string'
```

The filter works in the browser, and it tests on its own as a function, but I don't want to ship code with warnings.

Comment: Re what options can be passed to createLocalVue: I had a similar situation so I just checked the source code of that method, and the only option it takes is `errorHandler` (which is documented).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`createLocalVue` returns a Vue constructor, which includes the `filter` method for registering filters:

```js
import { createLocalVue, mount } from '@vue/test-utils'

const localVue = createLocalVue()

localVue.filter('myFilter', myFilter)

mount(TestComponent, {
  localVue
})
```

Alternatively you could install the filter globally on the Vue constructor before mounting your component:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.filter('myFilter', myFilter)

mount(TestComponent)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also import your filter script if you're using it that way a la Nuxt.

```js
import "@/plugins/filters";

...your test
```